# How can a basis have free variables if it also has to be linearly independent? UPDATED: With examples

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Edit: Added examples

I am confused about how free variables work with linear independence in vector space bases.

I am using Linear Algebra and its Applications Fifth Edition. It  states -

"The columns of a matrix A are linearly independent if and only if Ax=0 has only the trivial solution."
and "The homogenous equation Ax=0 has a nontrivial solution if and only if the equation has at least one free variable."

What I understand from this is - An equation is only linearly independent if Ax=0 has ONLY 0 as a solution and if there is a free variable, Ax=0 will have a non zero solution. Therefore, if there is a free variable, it will be linearly dependent. A basis must be linearly independent though, so how can it have a free variable?

This is in the first chapter. In the fourth chapter it has a problem,

A = \begin{bmatrix}1&4&0&2&0\\0&0&1&-1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

And asks to find the basis. The answer is

a1,a2,a4 = {\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}}

I understand how to split it up into vectors, remove the ones without pivot positions etc. What is confusing me is that the book defines a basis as -

Let H be a subspace of a vector space V . An indexed set of vectors
B = {b1...bp} in V is a basis for H if

(i) B is a linearly independent set, and

(ii) the subspace spanned by B coincides with H; that is,
H = Span{b1...bp}

If the basis has a free variable, how can it be a linearly independent set based on the earlier theorems that stated that a set could not be linearly independent if it has a free variable?

Comment: I'd really like to see an example of both types of claims.  (Otherwise I'm just guessing what your textbook/instructor mean.)

Comment: @EricTowers Updated and clarified! Sorry, I realize my original post wasn't detailed enough.

Comment: "The homogeneous equation $Ax=0$ has a *nontrivial* solution if and only if the equation has at least one free variable." The word nontrivial implies that the solution vector is not the zero vector. For your other question, presumably you are asking for basis of the range. Note that the second column belongs to the span of the first, the fourth column is in the span of the first and third.

Comment: @DKS I'm a little confused what you mean by this, this is my first proof based class so I'm not experienced with this. What I understand from the first two axioms is - An equation is only linearly independent if Ax=0 has ONLY 0 as a solution and if there is a free variable, it will have a non zero solution. Therefore, if there is a free variable, it will be linearly dependent. A basis must be linearly independent though, so how can it have a free variable?

Comment: The point is that $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution if and only if the columns of $A$ are a basis. In particular when the columns of $A$ are not a basis, $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions. If the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent as mentioned above, then you can "forget" the vectors that are in the span of the others and obtain a basis as a result.

Comment: I note that the matrix you have mode from your $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_4$ has linearly independent **columns** and, as used in the equation $Ax = 0$, a free variable corresponding to the fourth **row**.  Rows aren't columns...